# Error trying to run sonarqube scanner using Jenkins

Tags: sonar-runner

We have sonarqube scanner 2.6.1 installed on our Jenkins host. When trying to run sonarqube scanner from the Jenkins job we see the below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString([B)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.sonar.core.util.UuidFactoryImpl.create(UuidFactoryImpl.java:78)
    at org.sonar.core.util.Uuids.create(Uuids.java:45)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentKeys.of(ComponentKeys.java:47)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentKeys.of(ComponentKeys.java:35)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addComponent(ComponentContainer.java:229)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addSingleton(ComponentContainer.java:221)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.<init>(ComponentContainer.java:104)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.<init>(ComponentContainer.java:95)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.<init>(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.<init>(GlobalContainer.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.create(GlobalContainer.java:52)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:102)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.start(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.start(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:220)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure
```

As part of the Jenkins job we are copying code workspace for a build that is JDK 1.7 and running sonarqube scanner using JDK 1.8. This is just how it was setup in our environment

Answer (score 0):

We resolved it by upgrading to sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778. Not sure why we saw this issue suddenly